# Show that a function is equal to this series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

Show that $$ (1-x)^{-1/2} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{{(2n)}!}{{{(n}!)}^2} \ \left ( \frac{x}{2} \right )^{2n}  $$

I have tried u substitution: $ u = 1-x^2 $. When I calculated $f(0)$, I got an undefined term. I have tried building off common Macluarin series such as $ \frac{1}{1-x}$ with no luck.

Comment: The usual Maclaurin series process works well here,  the $n$-th derivative is accessible.  If $f(x)=(1-x)^{-1/2}$, then $f(0)=1$, no problem at all.

Comment: I am probably missing something, but it seems to me that the right hand side is an even function while the left hand side is not.

Comment: You are right about even function on the right. That expression is not correct, but something not far from that is correct.

Comment: Differentiate a few times, set $x=0$. We get something like $(1/2)(3/2)(5/2)(7/2)$.  Make $1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7$ look nicer by multiplying and dividing by $(2)(4)(6)(8)$. That turns the top into something that has shape $(2k)!$ while at the bottom we get $2^k(k!)$. The other $k!$ comes from the Maclaurin/Taylor formula. Try it, you will like it.

Comment: Yes, minor typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume there is a typo in your question. Another way is to note that the Taylor series of the arcsin is $$ \arcsin\left(x\right)=\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{\left(2n\right)!}{2^{2n}\left(n!\right)^{2}\left(2n+1\right)}x^{2n+1}
 $$ hence if we derivate $$\left(1-x^{2}\right)^{-1/2}=\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{\left(2n\right)!}{2^{2n}\left(n!\right)^{2}}x^{2n}=\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{\left(2n\right)!}{\left(n!\right)^{2}}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2n}.$$

Comment: So the typo was on the LHS :$1-x$ should have been $1-x^2$

Comment: @user254665 Yes.

Comment: This is cheating, isn't it ? (As you need a table of series.)

Comment: @YvesDaoust Why? It's the Taylor series of a standard function. What's the problem?

Comment: If the series for the $\arcsin$ function comes off-the-shelf, so does that of $(1\pm x)^\alpha$. [For example, the Wikipedia page on Taylor series gives both.]

Comment: @YvesDaoust And so? Probably the OP doesn't know it, and he only asked how to prove his identity, and this is a way, the most rapid. So I don't see how it can be "cheating".

Comment: If fetching the series from a table is considered a proof, then fetching the right formula is faster. Otherwise you need to prove the $\arcsin$ formula, which is a useless detour.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I respect your opinion, but I don't agree with you. For example, as you probably already know, in this site there are a lot of questions like this, sums like $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}kx^{k}$. And often the answer is "Take the derivative of the Taylor series of...". So it's quite usually start with a Taylor series of a standard function.

Comment: That's assuming that the Taylor development of $\arcsin$ is a "well-known" fact, while that of $(1\pm x)^\alpha$ isn't. (Which you phrase as "$\arcsin$ is a standard function", possibly implying that $(1\pm x)^\alpha$ isn't.) We are in a somewhat subjective area, but if you take one development for granted, by symmetry you should take the other as well.

Comment: As regards me, I don't try to remember $\arcsin$ by heart. I just remember that the trick is to expand $(1-x)^{-1/2}$ by the generalized binomial theorem, plug $x^2$ and integrate term-wise.

Comment: @YvesDaoust What is "well-know" or not is subjective. I started from this because I thought that it's instructive solve this kind of sums just considering as derivative of a function that we could know the power series. I think it's more naturally consider the series of $\arcsin$  series, and the other functions that we usually use. Probably for you in this case is the binomial theorem. However, thank you for the consideration, it's interesting to see other point of view :)

Comment: You are welcome. Such situations are typical of many questions on this site: the OPs often do not/cannot specify what is "allowed".

Answer (score 1):

The $n$th derivative is 
$$
 ((1-x)^{-1/2})^{(n)}=\frac{(2n-1)!!}{2^n}\frac1{(1-x)^{(2n+1)/2}}
$$
So the Macluarin series is
$$
(1-x)^{-1/2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(2n-1)!!}{2^n}\frac{x^n}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(2n)!}{2^n2\cdots2n}\frac{x^n}{n!} =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}\left(\frac{x}{2^2}\right)^n
$$

Answer (score 0):

Using [Binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series),

$$(1-x)^{-1/2}=\sum_{r=0}^\infty\dfrac{-1/2(-1/2-1)\cdots\{-1/2-(r-1)\}}{r!}(-x)^r$$

Now $\displaystyle-1/2(-1/2-1)\cdots\{-1/2-(r-1)\}$

$\displaystyle=\left(-\dfrac12\right)^r1\cdot3\cdot5\cdots(2r-1)$

$\displaystyle=\left(-\dfrac12\right)^r\dfrac{(2r)!}{2^r r!}$

Comment: @AndréNicolas, Yes!  For $(1-x)^{-m}$  each term has $$(-x)^r\cdot\left(-\dfrac1m\right)^r=+\left(\dfrac xm\right)^r$$